# Using the scanner class to parse a file but it takes far too long to run

Tags: android, performance, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a file containing around 39000 ints seperated by commas with 13 ints on each line so i set up a file reader and a scanner to read and parse it however it litterally takes over an hour to run. I think I probably need to use a bufferedreader but not sure how to implement it. Can anybody suggest a better (faster) way of doing this?

Here's my code:

```
public class ECGFilereader { // reads the ecg files from the SD card 

public final static int numChannels = 12;   // the data is stored in 12 channels, one for each lead
public final static int numSamples = 3000; //500 = fs so *6 for 6 seconds of data
private File file;
private Scanner scanner;
short [] [] ecg = new short [numChannels] [numSamples]; //Creates a short called ecg in which all of the samples for each channel lead will be stored

 public ECGFilereader (String fname) throws FileNotFoundException 
 {
    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/1009856.txt");     //accesses the ecg file from the SD card

    scanner = new Scanner(file);

    scanner.useDelimiter(",|\\r\\n");   //sets commas and end's of lines as separators between each int
 }

public boolean ReadFile(Waveform[] waves) // sorts data into and array of an array (12 channels each containing 3000 samples)
{
    for (int sample=0; sample<numSamples && scanner.hasNextInt(); sample++)     //
    {
        scanner.nextInt();
        for (int chan = 0; chan<numChannels; chan++)
        {
            if(scanner.hasNextInt())
                ecg [chan] [sample] = (short) scanner.nextInt();        

            else if (scanner.hasNextLine())
            {   scanner.nextLine();
            }
            else return false;
        }   
    }
    for (int chan=0; chan<numChannels; chan++)
        waves[chan].setSignal(ecg[chan]); // sets a signal equal to the ecg array of samples for each channel
    return true;

}
}
```

EDIT:

I have now removed the scanner class completely and it works perfectly with the following code:

```
public boolean ReadFile(Waveform[] waves) // sorts data into and array of an array (12 channels each containing 3000 samples)
{
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String reader = "";
    for (int sample=0; sample<numSamples; sample++){
    if ((reader = in.readLine()) == null) {
        break;}
    else {
        String[] RowData = reader.split(","); // sets the commas as separators for each int.
        for (int chan=0; chan <12 && chan<RowData.length; chan++)
            ecg [chan][sample]= Integer.parseInt(RowData[chan+1]); //parses each int from the current row into each channel for the ecg[]
        }
    }
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    }
    for (int chan=0; chan<numChannels; chan++)
        waves[chan].setSignal(ecg[chan]); // sets a signal equal to the ECG array of samples for each channel
    return true;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your delay is coming from the Scanner and not the final setSignal loop you put in?

I would recommend using [TraceView](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to figure out exactly where your program is hanging up.  It helped me greatly with a similar problem.

Let me know if this helps.  I suggest putting the start and stop points at the beginning and end of the first loop.  Like this:

public class ECGFilereader { // reads the ecg files from the SD card

public final static int numChannels = 12;   // the data is stored in 12 channels, one for each lead
public final static int numSamples = 3000; //500 = fs so *6 for 6 seconds of data
private File file;
private Scanner scanner;
short [] [] ecg = new short [numChannels] [numSamples]; //Creates a short called ecg in which all of the samples for each channel lead will be stored

```
public boolean ReadFile(Waveform[] waves) // sorts data into and array of an array (12
channels each containing 3000 samples)
{   
Debug.startMethodTracing("scanner");
for (int sample=0; sample<numSamples && scanner.hasNextInt(); sample++)     //
{
    scanner.nextInt();
    for (int chan = 0; chan<numChannels; chan++)
    {
        if(scanner.hasNextInt())
            ecg [chan] [sample] = (short) scanner.nextInt();        

        else if (scanner.hasNextLine())
            scanner.nextLine();

        else return false;
    }   
}
Debug.stopMethodTracing();

Debug.startMethodTracing("setSignal");
for (int chan=0; chan<numChannels; chan++)
    waves[chan].setSignal(ecg[chan]); 
    // sets a signal equal to the ecg array of samples for each channel
Debug.stopMethodTracing();
return true;
}
```

This way you will have 2 traceView files to analyze to see where your performance issues are coming from.

EDIT:

One other thing you need to make sure you're doing is checking if the external storage is available.  Do that with the following code:

```
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // We can only read the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
} else {
    // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
    //  to know is we can neither read nor write
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the help, I will look into TraveView for future reference. For this I completely replaced the scanner class and got it working in the end with some help from a friend. Will post what I did as an answer imminently. Also Thanks for the suggestion on checking the sd card is available.

Comment: No problem!  Glad you got your code working.  BufferedReader is what is generally recommended to use in most cases, anyways.  Don't forget to mark an answer as correct if it solved your problem!  Welcome to SO and good coding :)